# Angulr2: custom css conflict with third-party css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

In my Angular2 project, I extract some common css into a global-style.css file and link this in index.html.

I also link third-party css in index.html but third-party css conflict with my global-style.css.

Let's see a concrete example.

In my global-style.css I have a style

```
.display-none { display: none; }
```

In bootstrap css there is a style

```
input[type="file"] { display: block; }
```

When I want to hide file picker I write the code

```
<input class="display-none" type="file">
```

But file picker still display because `input[type="file"]` have higher specificity than `.display-none`. (according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

There is a Plunker live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/7HOT1if3ZhtSGu0UXOZX?p=preview

My question is, how to make my global-style.css have higher priority than other third-party css?
I know the way declaring `!important` but is there any other more elegant way? Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Use `/deep/` on the CSS you want to override in your files. example : `/deep/ .datepicker-input-icon {
  margin-right: 20px !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}`

Comment: This is an old question but here is one way to give `.display-none` a higher priority than `input[type="file"]`: make the selector more specific by combining the two, like this: `input[type="file"].display-none { display: none; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you might be looking for:

1. Put the bootstrap link before your 'global-style.css'. This will solve your problem as the order of the links is the order that the CSS will be brought in.
2. Just use !important. A 10 character solution isn't not elegant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!For the solution1, It does solve the problem css conflict having **same specificity**, but while bootstrap css have higher specificity it still override my css. For the solution 2, I have many global styles. If I add `!import` for every styles, there will be 100*10 character. I think it isn't so elegant.